# Delete all the rows in table

Tags: c#, for-loop, data-binding, delete-row

I am trying to delete all the rows in the table with for loop but i cant do it.
I am counting the rows from the table with reportBindingSource.count, but i cant find the way to delete the whole line FROM data base ( id, nameofcase, price).

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //delete all lines from the table

            count = reportBindingSource.Count;
            MessageBox.Show(count.ToString());

            for (int x = 0; x < count; x++) 
            {

                try
                {

                    //delete

                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("not deleted");
                }

                MessageBox.Show(x.ToString());
            }
            this.Close();

        }
```

Anyone can help me?

**UPDATE 1**

```
 try
                {

                    using(SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection("server=kosh-pc;User Id=root;Persist Security Info=True;database=lawyersprice"))
                    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE report", cnn))
                     {
                         cnn.Open();
                         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                     }

                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                }
```

I try this based on the answer but is not connecting and yes i have the .net installed

Comment: Are you trying to delete the rows from the in-memory BindingSource or you want to delete the rows in the database table ?

Comment: you know comment `//delete all lines from the table` wont really delete the rows, did you remove the delete code? why?

Comment: Have you actually looked at the message in the exception (and its type)? This may directly tell you how to avoid the error, otherwise it does give a significant clue.

Comment: @Steve I am trying to delete the rows from the database table

Comment: @Uriel_SVK i have try different for loops to delete the rows but they didn't work so i haven't put them here to be more clear. the // is just comments to remember what this area do.

Comment: @marios yeah but if you wont post the code its difficult to see what you tried and where you make mistake

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To remove all elements from the a BindingSource you need to simply call the

```
 reportBindingSource.Clear();
```

and no need to loop over the single elements

If you want to remove all the rows from the database table then you need to prepare and execute a Sql Command appropriate for your database type.

Example for MySql - Needs the [MySql NET Connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/) and the appropriate references to MySql.Data.dll

(Warning this removes the rows from the database without any exception)

```
 using(MySqlConnection cnn = new MySqlConnection(....connectionstring..))
 using(MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE yourTableName", cnn))
 {
     cnn.Open();
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
 }
```

instead, if you have a condition then you need

(This removes only the rows from the database that satisfy the condition)

```
 using(MySqlConnection cnn = new MySqlConnection(....connectionstring..))
 using(MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("DELETE FROM yourTableName WHERE ... your condition...", cnn))
 {
     cnn.Open();
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
 }
```

Comment: The database is Mysql

Comment: No big difference, just use the MySqlConnection and MySqlCommand. They are available if you install the NET MySql connector and add the appropriate references

Comment: Look carefully at my updated answer. When you connect to MySql you use the MySqlConnection and MySqlCommand, not the SqlConnection and SqlCommand. These are used to connect to Sql Server